# Creating dynamic inset map for Data Driven Pages using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, data-driven-pages, map-overviews

Included below  are two screenshots.

The one at the bottom is an example of an old inset map previously created which shows the extent of each data driven page.

The image  above that is a screenshot of my current predicament. Because this new project covers a much larger area and has many more pages (180 vs 35) the small inset map in the legend has to be zoomed out much farther to cover the whole area which makes it nearly impossible to see the Page Numbers when everything is actually printed out. The large purple quadrants are a viewport and each yellow box is a data driven page.

My supervisor suggested I preface the maps with a layout showing 4 different extents. Then depending on the data driven page, the extent of the inset map would just be one of these four squares and would have text denoting which section it is. This would show just a fourth of the map rather than the full extent which would allow the client to actually see the page numbers in the inset map.

I am trying to think of a rough way to approach this.

I was thinking I could add an attribute column for each of the DDP rectangles and specify which quadrant it lies within. Then I could add dynamic text in the Legend to denote which quadrant is being shown

I think my main problem lies with making the inset map actually change extent from quadrant to quadrant. It almost seems like I would need another set of data driven pages for these quadrants in the inset map, but I do not think that is possible.

[image: Different Viewport Sections]

[image: Inset Map of Data Driven Pages]

Comment: Did you think about 4 map projects?

Comment: Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331058/how-can-i-create-an-inset-map-in-ddp-that-zooms-to-a-feature-in-a-layer-besides/331239#331239