# Linking two different Data Driven Pages in different data frames

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages

I have a layer of data driven pages that go through this entire area, but the area covered is so large that it would be impossible to make out the page numbers in the inset map in the legend. What I am hoping to do would be to have the inset map cycle between the N, E, W, and S extents and then have a dynamic text element just saying which quadrant the map extents is currently located within. Each of these data driven pages have an attribute value denoting which quadrant they fall in (hence the symbology).

Is there a way for the inset map to grab a value from the main map's data driven page and then show the corresponding quadrant or is there another way to do this?

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1.

[image]

Comment: If you also want to ask about doing this using ArcGIS Pro and map series then please do that in a separate question so that you can describe what you’ve tried with that application

Comment: Does this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331058/how-can-i-create-an-inset-map-in-ddp-that-zooms-to-a-feature-in-a-layer-besides/331239#331239 help?